# NoneType object returns False when equated to None

Tags: python-2.7, nonetype

I have a function that doesn't return anything, and when I write `type(function())` I get type `NoneType`. But when `type(function()) == None`, the feedback is `False`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

`None` is a singleton object of type `NoneType`, but like any other object (well, any one without an odd `__eq__` method), it's not equal to its type.

The equivalent check would be `type(function()) == type(None)`, or, since type-checking is a bit silly in this case, `function() is None`.